# How to open a context menu when right clicking an item in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, contextmenu, right-click

Basically, I want to show a context menu when the user right clicks a valid item on my data grid, however, all the answers I've found are made to do this with a data grid view, which I can't use since I am working on a WPF project. To be clear, I know how to deal with the context menu when right clicking, however, I need the menu only to popup when the user right clicks a row in the data grid. Please help me c:

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
                    </Menu>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create ContextMenu.

```
    <DataGrid Name="dGrid">
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Click Here" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```